# Is there any way to create something similar to an object member function on a C struct?

Tags: c

Is there any way to create something similar to an object member function on a C struct? I have been doing some work with C and I am curious about how I can create some sort of encapsulation

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work

Comment: Yep this definitely seems like what I am looking for. Sorry about the duplication, I've been googling this for hours and couldn't come up with anything that concise